# How can I make a low poly triangular pendentive?

Tags: objects, geometry

[image]

I accidentally made this once, but I forgot how I did it. It's 3D, and it's the same dimension of a regular cube. I know how to make the arches, but I don't know how to fill it once the arches are in place.

Edit: I'd like an ability to see it as smooth while low-poly, if it's possible. I guess a triangular pendentive is a better way to explain it :)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Do you use the F2 add-on in your projects?

Comment: Glad to be here. I've seen a video tutorial just now on F2. It does seem useful for this task. My ultimate goal is to make the curve smooth, but this is a start.

Comment: If you would like to make it VERY smooth in all possible direction, you should not follow that topology. Between the arcs I see planes, that means there is no curvature of the faces. Would you like to achieve the same exact mesh you got that day or a [Pendentive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendentive)?

Comment: I'd like an ability to see it as smooth while low-poly, if it's possible. I guess a triangular pendentive is a better way to explain it :)

Comment: I suggest to edit your question with this info, so everyone can clearly see them. Filling the spaces with single quad faces given the arcs should be pretty straightfoward with F2, while obtaing a good low poly pendentive could be more challenging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use circle meshes to create the exact shape in your example image, if I understand correctly.

I created circles on three faces of a standard cube, removed doubles, deleted excess vertices, filled the faces, and fixed normals:

[image]

Comment: This will have to do for now. Thanks for the low poly tutorial and the key indications!

Answer (score 3):

Add circle, set vertices to 3. Convert it to 2D bezier curve and scale handles.
[image]

After that add sphere, scale rotate as you want. Set top view and do Knife Project with your curve object. Invert selection in face mode and delete faces.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a planar shape - I believe OP wants a 3D shape as in @bertmoog's answer.  [It wasn't particularly clear in the screenshot.](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/db/23/16/db2316079e31f729f317ddaae36e75d3.jpg)